# MI0283QT-17CP1 LCD with ILI9341V controller

Tags: lcd, stm32f4

I am trying to use the MI0283QT-17CP1 2.8' TFT LCD with the ILI9341V driver using the serial 8080 8 bit data protocol.
this is my initialization code:

```
/* Software reset */
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_RESET);
HAL_Delay(50);

LCD_Send_Command(0x34);   // TE off

LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_POWERA);
LCD_Send_data(0x39);
LCD_Send_data(0x2C);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_data(0x34); //33
LCD_Send_data(0x02);    //06
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_POWERB);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_data(0xC1);    //C3 / F9 / EA
LCD_Send_data(0x30);    //        / F0
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_DTCA);
LCD_Send_data(0x85);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);    //01
LCD_Send_data(0x78);    //79
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_DTCB);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);    //seems to be ok
LCD_Send_data(0x00);    //seems to be ok
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_POWER_SEQ);
LCD_Send_data(0x64);    //seems to be ok
LCD_Send_data(0x03);    //seems to be ok
LCD_Send_data(0x12);    //seems to be ok
LCD_Send_data(0x81);    //seems to be ok
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_PRC);
LCD_Send_data(0x20);    //seems to be ok
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_POWER1);
LCD_Send_data(0x21);//0x1B / 1D / 27 /21
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_POWER2);
LCD_Send_data(0x10);    // 01
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_VCOM1);
LCD_Send_data(0x3E);    //2D /3F / 33 / 4D / 4F
LCD_Send_data(0x33);    //33 /3C / 34 / 3B / 38
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_MAC);
LCD_Send_data(0x48);
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_PIXEL_FORMAT); //seems to be ok
LCD_Send_data(0x55);                    //seems to be ok
//LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_RGB_INTERFACE);
//LCD_Send_data(0x60);
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_FRC);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_data(0x18);
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_DFC);
LCD_Send_data(0x08);
LCD_Send_data(0x82);
LCD_Send_data(0x27);
//LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_3GAMMA_EN);
//LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_COLUMN_ADDR);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_data(0xEF);
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_PAGE_ADDR);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_data(0x01);
LCD_Send_data(0x3F);
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_GAMMA);
LCD_Send_data(0x01);
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_PGAMMA);
LCD_Send_data(0x0F);
LCD_Send_data(0x31);
LCD_Send_data(0x2B);
LCD_Send_data(0x0C);
LCD_Send_data(0x0E);
LCD_Send_data(0x08);
LCD_Send_data(0x4E);
LCD_Send_data(0xF1);
LCD_Send_data(0x37);
LCD_Send_data(0x07);
LCD_Send_data(0x10);
LCD_Send_data(0x03);
LCD_Send_data(0x0E);
LCD_Send_data(0x09);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_NGAMMA);
LCD_Send_data(0x00);
LCD_Send_data(0x0E);
LCD_Send_data(0x14);
LCD_Send_data(0x03);
LCD_Send_data(0x11);
LCD_Send_data(0x07);
LCD_Send_data(0x31);
LCD_Send_data(0xC1);
LCD_Send_data(0x48);
LCD_Send_data(0x08);
LCD_Send_data(0x0F);
LCD_Send_data(0x0C);
LCD_Send_data(0x31);
LCD_Send_data(0x36);
LCD_Send_data(0x0F);

LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_SLEEP_OUT);

HAL_Delay(1000);

LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_DISPLAY_ON);
LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_GRAM);
```

I am trying for start to draw the all screen in red (5-6-5 RGB format) and can't seem to draw anything... 
I already checked all the HW lines such as reset, CS, data/command and all the data lines.
Did anybody worked with this settings and can tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks,
Avner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I found the answer, it wasn't in the initilaiztion code, but in the coloring of the screen. forgot to add a Gram command that sets the writing of data to the screen sram.
so now my coloring function is like this:

```
    void LCD_MNG_FillRect(uint16_t Xpos, uint16_t Ypos, uint16_t Width, uint16_t Heigth, LCD_COLORS_NAMES Color)
{
        uint32_t Index;
        uint16_t DisplayColor;
        uint32_t Size = (uint32_t)(Width * Heigth);
        LCD_InitDrawImage(Xpos, Ypos, Width, Heigth);
        DisplayColor = LCD_MNG_CreateColor565((uint8_t)LCD_ColorsList[(int)Color].Red, (uint8_t)LCD_ColorsList[(int)Color].Green, (uint8_t)LCD_ColorsList[(int)Color].Blue);
        LCD_Send_Command(ILI9341_GRAM); // this was missing...

        for (Index = 0; Index < Size; Index++)
        {
                LCD_DisplayNextPoint(DisplayColor);

        }
}
```

I hope this will help others.